# How can I dynamically resize a div with a background image inside of it?

Tags: html, css

I want to dynamically resize a div, based on the size of the window I am in. I'm building a one-page scrolldown site, with 5 sections (all the size of a page) site with several images in it. On desktop each page is split into 2, with col-6s. On tablet/mobile, each half page is stacked with col-12s.

In my desktop version, all 5 pages have an image on the left 50% of the page, and text on the right 50%. On tablet/mobile, the image (aka left) div stacks on top of the text div (aka right).

In other words, height: 100% looks great on desktop, but as I scale down, the image is less and less % than at desktop height. For example, on an ipad the background-image might look perfect at 70% div height, on mobile 50% or so. I want the div always to be the height that makes the image look perfect, and make the right div switch to the same height. For example, if the image looks best at 50% height, I want the div to dynamically be that height, as well as the text div.

To show better, here are some images.

Desktop version at 100% height - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/24-inch-desktop-responsive_zps6mwocx8l.png

Desktop version at 50% height - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/desktop-50percent_zpsts2se3jo.png

Mobile version at 100% height - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/background-size%20cover_zpswc6knbqg.png

Mobile version at 50% height - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/mobile-50percent_zpsyuxcxdyr.png

HTML -

```
<section id="about" ng-controller="aboutController">    
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row about-row">

      <div class="about-left col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <!-- <img src="assets/images/jay-ocean.jpg" class="col-xs-12"/> -->
      </div>

      <div class="about-right col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="about-content">
          <div class="about-content-title">
            <h1><strong>I'M JAY.</strong></h1>
          </div>

          <div class="about-content-info">
            <p ng-if="about.firstParagraph">An entrepenurial minded, Full Stack Developer. Whenever I'm up against a challenge that I care about, it gives me a rush. Focusing on the big picture is important to me, but I never forget the smaller details. Anything that is not challenging is boring, and makes me yawn. Anything that is seemingly impossible interests me a lot. I'm ready to get to work.</p>

            <p ng-if="!about.firstParagraph">Currently seeking a Javascript position, using the MEAN stack, in New York City. Being innovative, ambitious, and hard working are values that are very important to me. I want to join a company that has similar values and has goals of reaching ridiculous levels of success, not just modest realistic ones. I love working with a solid team.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="about-button">
            <button ng-if="about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success" ng-click="about.switchParagraph()">MORE =></button>
            <button ng-if="!about.firstParagraph" class="label label-success"><a href="/portfolio">VIEW SKILLS</a></button>
          </div>

          <div class="about-personal-info">
            <h4>Email: jaybittner@gmail.com</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="about-icon">
            <a href="{{ profile.url }}" ng-repeat="profile in about.profiles"><img ng-src="{{ profile.icon }}" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

CSS -

```
#about {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,97,65,1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,97,65,1)), color-stop(7%, rgba(54,135,95,1)), color-stop(22%, rgba(36,123,85,1)), color-stop(53%, rgba(0,97,65,1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(34,121,84,1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(54,135,95,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(54,135,95,1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,97,65,1) 0%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 7%, rgba(36,123,85,1) 22%, rgba(0,97,65,1) 53%, rgba(34,121,84,1) 76%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 90%, rgba(54,135,95,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#006141', endColorstr='#36875f', GradientType=1 );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #101010;
}

#about .container-fluid, #about .row {
  height: 100%;
}

.about-left {
  height: 50%;
  background-image: url('../../images/jay-ocean.jpg'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-right: 3px solid #101010;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

/*.about-left img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}*/

.about-right {
  height: 50%;
  padding-top: 24vh;
  padding-left: 3.4vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-content {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.about-content-title {
  padding-bottom: -30px;
}

.about-content-title h1{
  font-size: 3.1vw;
  margin: 3px;
}

.about-content-info p {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-button button {
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  background-color: #101010;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
}

.about-button a {
  color: gray;
}

.about-personal-info h4 {
  font-size: 1vw;
  word-spacing: 0.3vw;
}

.about-icon img {
  height: 3.5vh;
  width: 1.75vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #101010;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are asking, but does something like this work?

http://codepen.io/kjantzer/pen/NGGqNm

The key is to use `background-image` with:

```
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Out of everything I have tried, this is working the absolute best. Looks good with every screen cut 50/50, and is also very responsive. It's automatic and requires almost 0 media queries, which is what I was aiming for. background position: center center; fixed the ugly look on tablet. Much appreciated. Thanks!